# iOS 7: How to change to another UIViewController from an others method?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have two UIViewControllers, each with their own views in the storyboard. In one of them i have a function, which got called, and i want it to channge to the other ViewControllers view. 
I tried this:

```
BRLoggedViewController *obj = [[BRLoggedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BRLoggedViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:NO];
```

I logged the first, it got called (i mean the constructor), but the the view doesn't change. What did i forget?
Thanks for helping

Comment: If you're using a storyboard, why instantiate from a NIB (does it exist)? Is the first view controller is a navigation controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use segues ? in storyboard, draw your segue, then in your code just trigger that segue

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueNameAsItIsInStoryboard" sender:self];
```

if required, manage your

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboard you have to get the view from the storyboard, something like this:

```
BRLoggedViewController *obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BRLoggedViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Make sure that the ViewController has the right storyboard identifier set in InterfaceBuilder for your Storyboard.

Comment: why not `self.storyboard` ?

Comment: Could use both, i suppose memory wise self.storyboard would be the way to go.  Editing...